# Reading file names and

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I would like to create a batch-file that reads the first 10 file names in a spefic directory, and then sets the paths to 10 different variables. For a simple example, the path would be *c:\test* and inside there, there would be lots of files named *file1.tif*, *file2.tif*, etc. I would like to set the variable `filepath1` equal to the path of the 1st file, which would be *c:\test\file1.tif*, and so on for the first 10 files. Here is the code:

```
@echo off
cd C:\TEST
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /f "delims=|" %%a IN ('dir /b') DO (
    CALL SET /a x = !x! +1
    if !x! == 1 (
        CALL SET /a filepath!x!="C:\TEST\%%a"
    )
)
echo %filepath1%
echo %filepath2%
pause
goto EOF
```

When I run the program, it seems to perform the FOR loop fine, but for `filepath1` it displays just `0` and it does not display anything for `filepath2`. I belive the problem is in the `if !X! == 1` and setting the `filepath!x!`. If I change anything to do with the `!x!`, it breaks the loop. What can I do to set the variables correctly and limit the loop to perform action on only 10 files?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure if I got your question correct, because your orginal code contains some things that wouldn't make sense then (or are at least not necessary) :-)

- the "delims=|" option you used is not doing anything in your case
- when `/a` option is used for arithmetic (see `help set`) and is wrong when used with your `set filepath!x!...` line.

Anyway, the following should work:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
cd C:\Test
FOR /f %%a IN ('dir /b') DO (
    SET /a x = !x! +1
    SET filepath!x!="C:\TEST\%%a"

    if !x! equ 10 goto done
)
:done
rem filepath1 to filepath10 are defined now, given there were up to 10 matching
rem files in the first place.

echo %filepath1%
echo %filepath2%

pause
```

The code above does not do any error checking and does not verify that the files in question are actually called `file1.tif` to `file10.tif`. From your question (and sample code) it is not quite clear if that is really necessary in your case. You might want to clarify that, so that the above code can be improved regarding it.